# Document library rendor error

Tags: document-library, error

When this view of my document library is selected the groups are collapsed by default. When I open the first group (that has no "Name" selected) the following rendering error occurs.

[image: Screenshot]

Any suggestions?

As you can see there should be 9 files displayed. This view has worked fine in the past. This morning I opened the folder in Windows Explorer view, copy and pasted some documents, edited in Datasheet View, modified the properties of one document, back to Show In Standard View and this is what it now looks like. I can still edit in Datasheet View.

Comment: Are other users seeing the same issue?

Comment: This is a private view but I will get someone else to create a similar view tomorrow and see what happens for them